# OpenGL 4.6 Game Program - Water Reflection - Flicker Problem

Tags: c++, opengl

With my water render, I am having an issue, where based on the camera position and orientation, there is a "flicker" effect/problem on the terrain in the game. Basically, a gray overlay "flickers" onto the terrain, but then disappears. This repeats as the camera position/orientation is changed.

Specifically, it happens on only specific terrain "islands" and near the part of the terrain which intersects the water quad.

So, to illustrate the issue:

Water with no flicker

[image]

Water with flicker; In the bottom right hand side of the image, there is a slight gray overlay on the "small" island that protrudes from the main island.

[image]

Additionally, here is an animated .gif demonstrating the issue:

[image]

As a final note, this flickering does not happen, say, for the large body of terrain in the background.

Could anyone please let me know what additional details I need to provide, as well as point me in the right direction as to the problem and possible resolution?

Thank you in advance!

---

Below is my process of mapping the reflection to the water quad:

I first created one frame buffer object upon program start up:
**Framebuffer Object Creation:**

```
// FBO objct
unsigned int framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

// generate texture
unsigned int texColorBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &texColorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

// attach it to currently bound framebuffer object
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer, 0);

unsigned int rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 1024, 768);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I created a single water quad:

```
// real_offsets needed for instancing
std::vector<glm::vec2> real_offsets;
real_offsets.push_back(glm::vec2(650, 450));
glm::mat4 waterQuad = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        waterQuad = translate(waterQuad, vec3(0, 480.0, 0));
        waterQuad = scale(waterQuad, vec3(100, 1, 100));
        objects.push_back(std::shared_ptr <Object>(new Object("waterpane_very_low.obj", waterQuad, real_offsets, true, false
            , glm::vec3(0.0, 0.5, 1.0))));
```

Then in the main game loop, I used the frame buffer object to save a snapshot of the scene:
**Main Game Loop:**

```
do {
    glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);

    // Use frame buffer object
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw scene with no water quad to FBO
    // [...]

    // Disable frame buffer object
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // Save frame buffer object texture to texture unit 0 to use later
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer);

    glDisable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);

    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw whole scene, including water quad as normal
    // [...]

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
```

In my normal object's shader, I enabled a clip plane to control what is drawn to the reflection texture: **NormalObjects.vertexshader:**

```
const vec4 plane = vec4(0,1,0,-480);
gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot( M * vec4(vertex,1), plane);
gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertex,1);
```

In my water.vertexshader, I performed necessary calculations to transform a local vertex: **water.vertexshader:**

```
// MVP_offset = P * V * M_offset, where M_offset depends on a vector of vecs2 passed in containing instancing offsets
        clipSpace =  MVP_offset * vec4(vertex,1.0);
        gl_Position = MVP_offset * vec4(vertex,1.0);    // instanced vertex
```

Then in my water.fragmentshader, I applied Blinn-Phong shading and sampled the reflection texture and projectively mapped it: **water.fragmentshader:**

```
// Sampler variable
uniform sampler2D waterTexture;

// Projectively map the reflection texture
vec2 clipProj = (clipSpace.xy / clipSpace.w) / 2.0 + 0.5;
clipProj.y *= -1.0f; // flip texture around

// waterTexture was assigned texture unit 0
vec4 finalVec = vec4(texture(waterTexture, clipProj).rgb, 1.0);

vec4 finalVec2 = finalVec * vec4(ambientComponent() + diffuseComponent(modelNormal,lightVec) + specularComponent(modelNormal, lightVec), 1.0);

FragColor = finalVec2;
```

Comment: Details would include what your code is doing...

Comment: @immibis Sorry, I've updated my post with the related code.